# Accessing Cloud SQL from a Compute Engine VM instance : do I have to copy the access token from my personnal computer to the VM instance?

Tags: google-cloud-sql, google-compute-engine

I'm trying to use Cloud SQL from my VM instance.
When creating the VM Instance I activated Cloud SQL Option for it.
The Cloud SQL instance authorizes my Compute Engine Project to access it.

At first I was expecting to have some tools like `google_sql.sh` installed on my VM since I had activated Cloud SQL on it but no :-/

In [Cloud SQL docs](https://developers.google.com/cloud-sql/docs/external) it says that I should copy my local access token to my VM Instance. 
My local machine is Mac OSX so the tokens are stored in :
`~user/Library/Preferences/com.google.cloud.plist` 
but on my Linux VM it's stored in:
`~user/.java/.userPrefs/com/google/cloud/sqlservice/oauth2/prefs.xml`.

Do I have to create a `prefs.xml` and copy it on my VM? (but I guess the XML schema is not the same between `com.google.cloud.plist` and `prefs.xml`?)

Does someone have `perfs.xml` example I could use as a template (unless schema is exactly the same as `com.google.cloud.plist` which I doubt)?

Thanks all for your help.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest thing is actually to include service account scopes when you create your instance.  [This page](https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/authentication#aliases) in the compute engine docs describes how to do it.  This maintains an access token in the compute engine instance's metadata server which the Cloud SQL tools can then access when they need to authenticate.  A similar technique works for cloud storage and other products.